# How to use a camera with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV. I have been playing around with it for an entire day trying to get it to recognize my camera. I just can't get it to work and I can't find any information about it.

My camera is a usb xbox live webcam, as soon as I connected it to my computer windows recognized it as if it were its own child and installed the drivers.

*DISCLAIMER* I'm like completely clueless as I have never worked with cameras before in code and I don't know how hard or difficult it would be to use one, nor do I know where to start, what information to look up, or anything like that. :( *DISCLAIMER*

I found this example on the opencv website at this url:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture

I copy and pasted the first one which says "Here is a simple framework to connect to a camera and show the images in a Window.". I formatted it correctly and got it to compile and run perfectly, but it gives the error "ERROR: capture is NULL" when I execute it(not a compiler error, its an error in the application)

Comment: Can [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) capture from your camera?

Comment: Not sure if I did it right, but one VirtualDub I went to File->Capture AVI     and when it asked for video device I picked my camera. The littel light on the camera turned on, but the preview on the program just shows a black box

Answer (score 5):

I think there are more than enough code on stackoverflow that shows how to do the trick:

[OpenCV 2.1: Runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438500/opencv-2-1-runtime-error/3444370#3444370)

[Unable to detect web cam in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325556/unable-to-detect-web-cam-in-open-cv/3325605#3325605)

[OpenCV: process every frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907028/opencv-every-frame-processing/3919216#3919216)

[OpenCV 'cvQueryFrame' non-blocking on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063096/opencv-cvqueryframe-non-blocking-on-os-x/4069537#4069537)

Answer (score -2):

as your given link :

```
 #include "cv.h" 
 #include "highgui.h"
```

---

try this one

```
#include <"opencv\cv.h> 
#include <"opencv\highgui.h> //"opencv is the file where cv.h and highgui placed
```

Comment: Don't use \ in a path... that's a brain dead Windows abortion. Use / as God intended.