# Converting cv::Mat to IplImage*

Tags: c++, opencv

The documentation on this seems incredibly spotty.

I've basically got an empty array of IplImage*s (IplImage** imageArray) and I'm calling a function to import an array of cv::Mats - I want to convert my cv::Mat into an IplImage* so I can copy it into the array.

Currently I'm trying this:

```
while(loop over cv::Mat array)
{
    IplImage* xyz = &(IplImage(array[i]));
    cvCopy(iplimagearray[i], xyz);
}
```

Which generates a segfault.

Also trying:

```
while(loop over cv::Mat array)
{
    IplImage* xyz;
    xyz = &array[i];
    cvCopy(iplimagearray[i], xyz);
}
```

Which gives me a compile time error of:
`error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat*’ to ‘IplImage*’ in assignment`

Stuck as to how I can go further and would appreciate some advice :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV C++ and cvSmooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449946/opencv-c-and-cvsmooth)

Comment: Update: from OpenCV 4, IplImage and all of what they now call "the legacy C API" will be progressively removed. In OpenCV 4.0 "alpha", IplImage is already gone - as is CvMat.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cv::Mat` is the new type introduce in OpenCV2.X while the `IplImage*` is the "legacy" image structure.

Although, `cv::Mat` does support the usage of `IplImage` in the constructor parameters, the default library does not provide function for the other way. You will need to extract the image header information manually. (Do remember that you need to allocate the IplImage structure, which is lack in your example).

Comment: It does provide a conversion to IplImage, creating a header without copying the data. So `IplImage* img = new IplImage(mat);` should work.

Comment: Actually, you can do this: `IplImage iplimg = mat;` and just use `&iplimg` wherever you need an `IplImage`. There is no need for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @etarion The IplImage doesn't have any function which can do that conversion. Why does IplImage* img = new IplImage(mat) is working?

Comment: @ajaxhe cv::Mat has a conversion operator to IplImage.

Comment: @etarion Yes, I found conversion operation in cv::Mat , the function name declaration is: operator IplImage() const;

Comment: This answer is false. See other answers, it can be converted very easily, should be removed from accepted answer as it might confuse other users.

Comment: @etarion, I know this is late. But I'm just wondering: If we use `new IplImage(mat)`, we need to *deallocate* it later by calling `free(...)` right? If it is the case, wouldn't it be better to use @Adi Shavit 's approach?

Comment: @AdiShavit Doing`IplImage iplimg = mat;` now doesn't work. It gives an error saying:

"conversion from ‘cv::Mat’ to non-scalar type ‘IplImage {aka _IplImage}’ requested"

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Please read the answer. `IplImage` is a C struct and you can't assign anything else to it. This is a really old question - you should really be using OpenCV and not IPL anyway.

Comment: "no suitable conversion from cv::Mat to IplImage exists"  This is the error message. IplImage* img = new IplImage(mat); does not work and IplImage iplimg = mat; does not work either as stated above. Consequently the accepted answer is correct. The comment stating that the answer is false should be deleted. I don't get why people are doing this.

Answer (score 21):

```
Mat image1;
IplImage* image2=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)image1);
```

Guess this will do the job.

**Edit:** If you face compilation errors, try this way:

```
cv::Mat image1;
IplImage* image2;
image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image1.cols,image1.rows),8,3);
IplImage ipltemp=image1;
cvCopy(&ipltemp,image2);
```

Comment: Could you explain this snippet ?

Comment: @chepseskaf cast syntax explicit conversion.

Comment: @William: I am getting _taking address of temporary_ warning while using above code

Comment: That's a suboptimal solution as you need to copy pixels manually.

Comment: Did you manage to convert it using only the header? Also, `IplImage` is obsolete. If you need efficient code, use `cv::Mat` instead.

Comment: (IplImage)image1 does not work.

Answer (score 14):

```
 (you have cv::Mat old)
 IplImage copy = old;
 IplImage* new_image = &copy;
```

you work with new as an originally declared IplImage*.

Comment: this is the best way and it works as like a charm! all the other ways are too complicated and this is the best one. Worked for me

Comment: The first line gives compiler error     "no suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Mat" to "IplImage" exists".

Comment: beware this create a use after free if you are not careful

Comment: This does not work anymore. Error message: "No suitable conversion existis from cv:Mat to IplImage."

Answer (score 12):

Here is the recent fix for dlib users [link](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/commit/54a9a5bbf3267386dd39a82fb792bab1bb60796c)

```
cv::Mat img = ...
IplImage iplImage = cvIplImage(img);
```

Comment: This is the only solution, which doesn't generate compiler error. I inserted it in my project with opencv420+dlib-19.8

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personaly I think it's not the problem caused by type casting but a buffer overflow problem; it is this line

```
cvCopy(iplimagearray[i], xyz);
```

that I think will cause segment fault, I suggest that you confirm the array iplimagearray[i] have enough size of buffer to receive copyed data

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenCV [cheat-sheet](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf) this can be done as follows:

```
IplImage* oldC0 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320,240),16,1);
Mat newC = cvarrToMat(oldC0);
```

The [cv::cvarrToMat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvarrtomat#Mat%20cvarrToMat%28const%20CvArr%2a%20arr,%20bool%20copyData,%20bool%20allowND,%20int%20coiMode%29) function takes care of the conversion issues.

Comment: I think cvarrToMat no longer exists in opencv 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

In case of gray image, I am using this function and it works fine! however you must take care about the function features ;)

```
CvMat * src=  cvCreateMat(300,300,CV_32FC1);      
IplImage *dist= cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(dist),IPL_DEPTH_32F,3);

cvConvertScale(src, dist, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be: when using external ipl and defining HAVE_IPL in your project, the ctor

```
_IplImage::_IplImage(const cv::Mat& m)
{
    CV_Assert( m.dims <= 2 );
    cvInitImageHeader(this, m.size(), cvIplDepth(m.flags), m.channels());
    cvSetData(this, m.data, (int)m.step[0]);
}
```

found in ../OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp is not used/instanciated and conversion fails.

You may reimplement it in a way similar to :

```
IplImage& FromMat(IplImage& img, const cv::Mat& m)
{
    CV_Assert(m.dims <= 2);
    cvInitImageHeader(&img, m.size(), cvIplDepth(m.flags), m.channels());
    cvSetData(&img, m.data, (int)m.step[0]);
    return img;
}

IplImage img;
FromMat(img,myMat);
```