# OpenCV C++ and cvSmooth

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Anyone know what could be problem:

```
cvSmooth(origImage, grayImage1, CV_BLUR,3);
```

I received error:

```
error: cannot convert `cv::Mat' to `const CvArr*' for argument `1' to `void 
cvSmooth(const CvArr*, CvArr*, int, int, int, double, double)'
```

If I use:

```
cvtColor(origImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

All worked fine. capturing is from laptop camera(realtime).

Comment: What you think?  With cvtColor all work fine. origImage is color realtime "picture" from camera...

Comment: So you think that I need picture not video?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cv::Mat` is a new structure from the C++ version of OpenCV. `cvSmooth()` is from the old C API. Do not mix the C interface with the C++!

I'll suggest that you take a moment to read the [introduction](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/introduction.html).

Also, if you check `opencv/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp` you'll see that `cv::boxFilter()` is the equivalent for `cvSmooth(CV_BLUR)` on the new C++ interface.

Comment: Updated answer. The equivalent for what you are looking for is `cv::boxFilter()`.

Comment: This was also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870927/what-is-the-c-replacement-to-the-old-cvsmoothsrc-dst-cv-median-3

Answer (score 2):

Be careful not to mix the OpenCV 1.x API (CvArr) with the 2.x API (cv::Mat).
I guess you tried an example from somewhere.