# What is the C++ replacement to the old cvSmooth(src, dst, CV_MEDIAN, 3)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am converting old OpenCV code over to the new C++ api, and I am not sure how this gets translated.

I have a line executing what's in the title, `cvSmooth(src, dst, CV_MEDIAN, 3);` and I'm not sure what the "proper" analogue is in the new C++ api.

What would it be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=cvsmooth#smooth): "The function is now obsolete. Use `GaussianBlur()`, `blur()`, `medianBlur()` or `bilateralFilter()`".

[Tutorial using them.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html)

Comment: Both links are now broken :(