# 'cvSmooth': identifier not found

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to smooth an image using cvSmooth function but when I run the program I get an error !
 my code is :

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
IplImage* img ;
img = cvLoadImage ("c:\\try.png");
cvSmooth( img, img, CV_GAUSSIAN,11,11);
cvShowImage("",img);
cv::waitKey( 15000 ) ;
return 0;
};
```

Error list is :
error C2065: 'CV_GAUSSIAN' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'cvSmooth': identifier not found

Comment: What includes do you have in your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV C++ and cvSmooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449946/opencv-c-and-cvsmooth)

Comment: I have tow includes : 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>

Comment: And what version of OpenCV do you use? I'm using 2.4.8 and your code will compile just fine.

Comment: 2.4.3 with visual c++ 2010

Answer (score 0):

## Rule1 - don't use the outdated c-api

please, forget about it, it's dead and gone.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 

int main()
{
  cv::Mat img = cv:imread("c:\\try.png");

  cv::Mat blurred;
  // see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur)
  cv::GaussianBlur(img,blurred(cv::Size(11,11),0); 
  cv::imshow("lala", blurred);
  cv::waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really I don't want that, but the supervisor forced me to use Iplimage rather than cvmat, So no other choice:)

Comment: please, point your supervisor at [current reality](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/)