# openCV get subimage in C

Tags: c, image, opencv

I am using OpenCV for image manipulation in C.  Please forgive me if this question is answered in the documentation, but I have found the OpenCV docs to be pretty badly formed and difficult to read.

I have an `CvMat*` that i have extracted from an image file as below:

```
CvMat* mat = cvLoadImageM((char*) filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

What I need to do is get a subimage of that by cropping out a certain bounded region.  A logical command for this might be:

```
CvMat* subMat = cvGetSubImage(mat, minx, maxx, miny, maxy);
```

where `minx`, `maxx`, `miny`, and `maxy` define the boundaries of the cropped region.  Is there a built in way to do this easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)/

In which the tutorial does the following on a Region of Interest:

```
cvSetImageROI(img1, cvRect(10, 15, 150, 250));
IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),
                           img1->depth,
                           img1->nChannels);
cvCopy(img1, img2, NULL);
cvResetImageROI(img1);
```

OpenCV has built in capabilities for setting the region which you care about and copying that region out of an image, just as you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a sub-pixel accurate rectangular section of a src image use cvGetRectSubPix or cv::getRectSubPix (this creates an individual copy of all the data, this is not a ROI!)

Example:

```
cv::Size size(dst_width,dst_height);
cv::Point2f center(src_centerx,src_center_y);
cv::Mat dst;
cv::getRectSubPix(src,size, center,dst,CV_8U);
```

Comment: Oh, btw: for ROIs I use:  
`cv::Mat newRoi = srcMat(cv::Rect(roiX,roiY,roiW,roiH));`

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is done by cropping an `ROI` (region of interest). This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110427104424/http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29) goes into some detail on cropping:

```
/* load image */
IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage("elvita.jpg", 1);

/* sets the Region of Interest
   Note that the rectangle area has to be __INSIDE__ the image */
cvSetImageROI(img1, cvRect(10, 15, 150, 250));

/* create destination image
   Note that cvGetSize will return the width and the height of ROI */
IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),
                               img1->depth,
                               img1->nChannels);

/* copy subimage */
cvCopy(img1, img2, NULL);

/* always reset the Region of Interest */
cvResetImageROI(img1);
```

To convert between `IplImage` (legacy OpenCV) and `cvMat` (OpenCV 2.x), simply use the `cvMat` constructor or look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage) for more methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756505/croping-an-image-in-ios-uisng-opencv-face-detect I facing cropping problem in iphone with opencv. Can please have a look.. My ROI are getting wrong I gues..