# How to send Bitmap using a Socket?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-camera

I have a Bitmap image that I want to send using the Socket class. The Bitmap needs to be sent from the Android client to a server. The server is a C++ program. How do I this?

I was looking at Android's Bitmap class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html). But it doesn't really talk about it.

Also how do I decode this Bitmap on the server side? The server is running a OpenCV program and I need to interpret the Bitmap as an IplImage (IplImage is an OpenCV struct that represents an image). If I have a image buffer, I can set IplImage to point to this buffer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location. If you can save bitmap to a file, you can send bitmap to socket. Just change `FileOutputStream` to `Socket.getOutputStream()` or the stream you have.

Comment: And then on Server side, use `imdecode` or `imread` to turn `png` to `Mat`. The turn `Mat` to `IplImage` by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to send JPEG(or PNG) version of this bitmap as a byte[] to the server.

On the server side you can easily decode this byte array to OpenCV IplImage or Mat.

Comment: Is there a OpenCV function to read bytes and convert from JPEG to IplImage or Mat?

Comment: @johnchen902 gave the correct answer above: you need to use either `imread` or `imdecode`. It returns `Mat`, but you can easily convert it to `IplImage`. `IplImage lpl = mat;`.