# How to deep copy from cv::Mat to IplImage?

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-copy, iplimage

In a function like this

```
void ipl_in_ipl_out(IplImage* src, IplImage* dst) {
    cv::Mat src_mat(src);
    dst = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage) src_mat);
}
```

when out the function, there is no data in dst. And how to deep copy from  cv::Mat to IplImage? I want to use cv::Mat to process, but in and out of a function should be IplImage*.

I've also tried to make src_mat as a Class member, but failed. And tried methods in [Converting cv::Mat to IplImage*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage).

So how to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: please avoid using deprecated IplImages in the first place.

Comment: @Quker I think my question to you is _why_ to use deep copy from cv::Mat to IplImage. You can most certainly avoid it.

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage- As suggested above, unless you are using a legacy library which needs `IplImage` as input paramter, please avoid the same.

Comment: Thank you all, this is a legacy library. And I must use IplImage* as input and output.