# No suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Mat" to "IplImage" exists

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++

I am traying to convert a cv::Mat to IplImage in pc with this caracteristcs:

- opencv: 3.4.14
- OS: Win 10
- code: c++

An example of the differents options:

```cpp
cv::Mat MBin = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(64, 64), CV_32FC1);

IplImage* image0= new IplImage(MBin);
IplImage image1 = MBin;
IplImage* image2 = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)MBin);

IplImage* image3;
image3 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(MBin.cols, MBin.rows), 8, 3);
IplImage image4 = MBin;
cvCopy(&image4, image3);
```

Where imageX appears produces the title error.

Comment: don't use obsolete C api!

Comment: It is a code with a hundreds of classes, I can not change all the C api.

Comment: @SSR You don't have to, just use the C++ API.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution, which doesn't generate compiler error:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>

Mat Img = imread("1.jpg");

IplImage IBin_2 = cvIplImage(MBin);
IplImage* IBin = &IBin_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `opencv3.x`, `Mat` has a constructor `Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);`. But in `opencv3.x`, `Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);` constructor is canceled.

So, you could refer to the following example to convert `Mat` to `IplImage`.

```
//Mat—>IplImage
//EXAMPLE:
//shallow copy：
Mat Img=imread("1.jpg");
IplImage* pBinary = &IplImage(Img);
//For a deep copy, just add another copy of the data:
IplImage *input = cvCloneImage(pBinary)
```

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
//opencv 4.5.2

IplImage* IplImage_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img.cols, img.rows), 8, 1);

cv::Mat MatImg(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(0));

MatImg = cv::cvarrToMat(IplImage_img);

img.copyTo(MatImg);
```