# Problem with deprecated conversion from cv::mat to IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv

I know there were already questions like this in the past but all the answers seem not to work anymore since some functions are deprecated so I hope you can help me.

That's what I try to do :

```
IplImage* image = 0;
Mat frame; 
image = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)frame);
```

Basically I get an error because of the last line :

`E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Mat" to "IplImage" exists`

By the way if instead there is a manual way to convert Mat to IplImage it's also great for me.

PS : I'm trying to use an old code so it doesn't bother me if Mat is the new standard in OpenCV and not advised using IplImage.

PS2 : If there is an old version of OpenCV that can do this without errors it's also OK.

Thank you!

Comment: conversion shouldnt be a problem. IplImage should provide a constructor that accepts data pointers and step values. I worked with IplImages and IPP about 12 years ago. But I dot know whether cloning an image (the cvCloneImag call) is still available in your environment?!?

Comment: This looks like an answer that applies https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664671/4117728. Manually doing the conversion is unlikely deprecated

Comment: or how about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683381/4117728 ? I don't understand that you say you are using an old version hence `IplImage` is fine, but at the same time you say solutions you found are outdated. The question would be more clear if you show the solutions you found and why they didnt work

Comment: I tried all of the solutions above and suprisingly they don't work since they get the same error ( no conversion from cv::Mat to IplImage ), btw if this can help I'm using OpenCV 4.5.5 (latest)

Comment: In my opencv 4.5.x environment I dont even have access to the IplImage type anymore. Can you tell a bit about your environment? I think you only have to set the `ipl.imageData = mat.data; ipl.width=img.cols; ipl.height=img.rows; ipl.widthStep=img.step;` but you might need to deep-copy the iplImage afterwards, before the cv::Mat leaves scope.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question but I use OpenCV 4.5.5 in VS2019 (sorry I'm a total rookie)

Comment: What do you #include to get access to the IplImage type?

Answer (score 0):

I try to make hand-crafted conversion. In my enviroment it works well (OpenCV 2.4.9).
Be carefull with `pix_type` variable value.

```
Mat frame_gray = imread("img.bmp");
int pix_type = IPL_DEPTH_8U;
IplImage* img = cvCreateImage(frame_gray.size(), pix_type , frame_gray.channels());
img->imageData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame_gray.data);
img->widthStep = frame_gray.step;
```

Comment: but as Micka says, you should think about deep-copy. I think.

Micka:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743095/problem-with-deprecated-conversion-from-cvmat-to-iplimage/70751337#comment125062825_70743095

Comment: The OP says they're [using OpenCV 4.5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743095/problem-with-deprecated-conversion-from-cvmat-to-iplimage#comment125062480_70743095). Does your approach work in 4.5.5?

Comment: In my OpenCV 4.5.5 version does not defined IplImage type.

Presented solution is redundant in memory (extra memory allocation in `cvCreateImage(frame_gray.size(), pix_type , frame_gray.channels())`). 
The better way is:
`Mat frame_gray = imread("img.bmp");
int pix_type = IPL_DEPTH_8U;
IplImage img;
img.height = frame_gray.rows;
img.width = frame_gray.cols;
img.nChannels = frame_gray.channels();
img.depth = pix_type;
img. imageSize = frame_gray.rows * frame_gray.step;
img.imageData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame_gray.data);
img.widthStep = frame_gray.step;`

Comment: To avoid problems with deep-copy and `cv::Mat` scope, just always contain your data in `cv::Mat` type and use conveter in places, only before using `IplImage` type

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of OpenCV (3.9 and later) you can use function cvIplImage:

```
Mat matImage;
IplImage iplImage = cvIplImage(matImage);
```