# convert cv::mat to IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat m = Mat(4, 4, CV_8UC3);
IplImage * iplImage = cvIplImage(m);
```

error: cannot convert ‘_IplImage’ to ‘IplImage*’ {aka ‘_IplImage*’} in initialization

opencv 4.5.3
ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You don’t. `IplImage` is gone, dead, defunct, never to return. There is no support in OpenCV 4. Do not use it.

Comment: Have a look at the intel performance library reference manual. Fill the IplImage header with mat.data, size and widthStep and use ipl functions to deep copy the data if necessary.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage

Comment: @wohlstad Do any of the solutions suggested there actually work in OpenCV 4?

Answer (score 0):

In opencv 4.5 there is still a ctor of `IplImage` that takes a `cv::Mat`.
There is also a function `cvIplImage` to convert `cv::Mat` to `IplImage`.

However - as you can see in `...\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h`, some code is only available if you compiled opencv with the proper flags (e.g. `CV__ENABLE_C_API_CTORS` for the `IplImage` ctor).